# Kafka Consumers in Spark Streaming - Parallel Consumption in Worker Nodes

Tags: streaming, apache-kafka, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark Streaming and I have 5 worker nodes in my cluster. The goal is to consume a Kafka topic and save it directly into a NoSql database like HBase or DynamoDB. **I'm trying to understand how Spark handles Kafka Consumer instances and distributes them across the Workers** (Spark 0.9.0 and Kafka 0.8).

If I create a Kafka stream by

```
    val topicMap = Map("myTopic" -> 1)
    val kafkaDStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zookeeper, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
```

and run stream operations like

```
    val valueStream = kafkaDStream.map(
        s => {
            val json = new JsonWrapper
            val js = json.parse(s)
            val a = (js \ "a").toString
            val b = (js \ "b").toString
            val c = (js \ "c").toString
            (a, b, c)
        }
    )

    valueStream.foreachRDD(
        rdd => {
            rdd.foreach(
                row => // put (a,b,c) into DB (HBase or DynamoDB)
            )
        }
    )
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**where exactly are the Kafka Consumers created?** Does the driver program construct the Consumer instances and ship them over to the workers or do workers create Consumer's as needed?

Here are more details on the JsonWrapper in case you need it:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

class JsonWrapper extends Serializable {
    lazy val jsObj = Json
    def parse(s: String) = jsObj.parse(s)
}
```

This class *lazily* references the Json singleton (by Play) and is shipped over to each worker when the program starts.

Comment: Have a look into the code of `KafkaInputDStream`. That's where all the kafka related stuff happens.